# How to take inceremental backup in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, backup

I want to perform a backup and restore process in my project. I used `snapshotdeletionpolicy` to take a hot backup of my indexes to another location.

Is it possible to take a incremental backup in lucene? (For e.g: if I added 100 documents in lucene than how should I update those indexes during backup at my backup location)

If so, how should I achieve this? Will `snapshotdeletionpolicy` help me do this?

Comment: It looks like wrapping your SnapshotDeletionPolicy in a [`PersistentSnapshotDeletionPolicy`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/PersistentSnapshotDeletionPolicy.html) may help you here.  Not quite entirely sure it's what your looking for, but worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

By using ReplicationHandler we can update the index with in 10sec in master copy and get the backup also, once check this url

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication